# Dynamic width of an element in jade 

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am trying to design a progress bar and I want to try to set the width of the bar depending on some mathematical calculations.

Below is working fine, since I am hardcoding the width to 60%

```
.pledged(style="width:60%")
```

I want to do something like this:

```
.pledged(style="width:((totalVotes - votesRemaining)*100)%")
```

Is it possible what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to add `#{}` to get access to your variables:

```
.pledged(style="width:#{totalVotes - votesRemaining)*100}%")
```